# Getting count of all possible substrings of length n in a file? (excluding spaces)

Tags: python, macos, shell, unix, awk

I have some export files, you can assume they have many words in a single line and no line is special. I saw this post to generate different words in a file

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286464/all-possible-permutations-of-words-in-different-files-in-pairs

and there are also some other variants of word search in a file.

But what I need is something like this for substrings of length four. Here we have the substring and the count of it.

Example file content

```
no apples 
no apples
mango is great
banana is expensive
test
```

Example output is

```
appl 2
pple 2
ples 2
mang 1
ango 1
grea 1
reat 1
bana 1
anan 1
nana 1
expe 1
xpen 1
pens 1
ensi 1
sive 1
nsiv 1
test 1
```

The substrings do not necessarily have any meaning, they are just substrings of the file. The file is not large, less than 5MB in the worst case, actually there are multiple files but I merged them before the analysis.

I wanted to ask in SO because in case this needs a shell/phyton script written, but if we can do this easily with commands, that is more appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution to get a list of all `n` letter substrings and their frequencies:

```
awk -v n=4 '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
   for (j=1; j<=length($i)-n+1; j++)
      w[substr($i, j, n)]++
}
END {
   for (i in w) print i, w[i]
}' file
```

```
appl 2
ensi 1
nana 1
mang 1
sive 1
anan 1
nsiv 1
grea 1
pens 1
xpen 1
bana 1
ples 2
pple 2
expe 1
reat 1
ango 1
```

Comment: I will provide a small content that I know the counts of the substrings. It may be for words of lenght four to make it easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl as well

```
perl -lne ' while(/(\S+)/g) { $x=$1; 
      while($x=~/\b(?=(\w{4}))|\B(?=(\w{4}))\B|(?=(\w{4}))\b/g) { $kv{"$1$2$3"}++ }} 
       END { print "$_ $kv{$_}" for(keys %kv) }  ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat test.txt
no apples
no apples
mango is great
banana is expensive
test

$ perl -lne ' while(/(\S+)/g) { $x=$1; 
     while($x=~/\b(?=(\w{4}))|\B(?=(\w{4}))\B|(?=(\w{4}))\b/g) { $kv{"$1$2$3"}++ }}
       END { print "$_ $kv{$_}" for(keys %kv) }  ' test.txt
nsiv 1
xpen 1
reat 1
ensi 1
sive 1
ples 2
pple 2
test 1
appl 2
expe 1
anan 1
mang 1
ango 1
bana 1
pens 1
grea 1
nana 1

$
```

You can parameterize inside the BEGIN block as

```
$ perl -lne ' BEGIN { $t=qr(\w{5}) } 
     while(/(\S+)/g) { $x=$1; while($x=~/\b(?=($t))|\B(?=($t))\B|(?=($t))\b/g)
        { $kv{"$1$2$3"}++ }} 
           END { print "$_ $kv{$_}" for(keys %kv) }  ' test.txt
great 1
pples 2
apple 2
expen 1
nsive 1
banan 1
anana 1
ensiv 1
pensi 1
xpens 1
mango 1

$
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another solution that worked in my mac.

Comment: glad that it worked!.. I just added how to parameterize it.. pls check

Comment: Interesting. Here's another take, using `substr` to go through length-4 strings in each word: `echo "banana is expensive, apple is great" | perl -wnE'while (/(\S+)/g) { $i=0;  say $s while length($s = substr $1, $i++, 4) >= 4 }`.  Brings up the issue of punctuation (just one of the many problems with working with natural language); a simple way, use `\w` instead of `\S`. But then what about hyphenated words? Perhaps use `[\w-]` then.

Answer (score 1):

something like below could do what you need :

```
while read line 
do 
  for word in $line 
  do 
  [[ ${#word} -eq 3 ]] && echo "$word" $(grep -c "$word" your_file)  
  done 
done < your_file
```

It will read your file line by line, word by word. If the word length is 3, it will output the word and the number of its occurences in the file

Comment: will test your solution soon but just provided an example, fyi

Comment: sorry, it looks your scripts counts the words not all subscripts. that is my bad on writing the question.  I provided an example, now it is clear.

Comment: but your answer maybe more helpful this way, I guess people mostly need words not substrings.

Answer (score 1):

so the temptation here is to nest loops... but you don't want to do that, certainly not for N>3...

there are 2 nice things in python that will make this pretty easy

- filter
- collections.Counter

.

```
from collections import Counter

s = open(somefile).read()
# now you have a string with contents of file.
l = s.split()
# now you have a list of words of all lengths
l_filtered = filter(lambda x: len(x)==n, l)
#now you have a filtered list of only words of len n
print (Counter(l_filtered))
#your answer as a dict like Counter object
```

Comment: will test your solution soon but just provided an example, fyi

Comment: the only thing you need to provide is and int `n` and the path to a file in `somefile`